# Segment tree implementation

Tags: c++, segment-tree

I was learning segment tree from this page : http://letuskode.blogspot.com/2013/01/segtrees.html

I am finding trouble to understand various fragments of code.I will ask them one by one.Any help will be appreciated.

Node declaration:

```
struct node{
    int val;
    void split(node& l, node& r){}
    void merge(node& a, node& b)
    {
        val = min( a.val, b.val );
    }
}tree[1<<(n+1)];
```

1.What will the split function do here ?

2.This code is used for RMQ . So I think that val will be the minimum of two segments and store it in some other segment.Where the value will be saved?

Range Query Function:

```
node range_query(int root, int left_most_leaf, int right_most_leaf, int u, int v)
{
    //query the interval [u,v), ie, {x:u<=x<v}
    //the interval [left_most_leaf,right_most_leaf) is 
    //the set of all leaves descending from "root"
    if(u<=left_most_leaf && right_most_leaf<=v)
        return tree[root];
    int mid = (left_most_leaf+right_most_leaf)/2, 
        left_child = root*2, 
        right_child = left_child+1;
    tree[root].split(tree[left_child], tree[right_child]);
    //node l=identity, r=identity;
    //identity is an element such that merge(x,identity) = merge(identity,x) = x for all x
    if(u < mid) l = range_query(left_child, left_most_leaf, mid, u, v);
    if(v > mid) r = range_query(right_child, mid, right_most_leaf, u, v);
    tree[root].merge(tree[left_child],tree[right_child]);
    node n;
    n.merge(l,r);
    return n;
}
```

1.What is the use of the array tree and what values will be kept there ?

2.What will this statement : tree[root].split(tree[left_child], tree[right_child]); do ?

3.What will those statements do ? :

```
node n;
n.merge(l,r);
return n;
```

Update and Merge Up functions:
I am not understanding those two functions properly:

```
void mergeup(int postn)
{
    postn >>=1;
    while(postn>0)
    {
        tree[postn].merge(tree[postn*2],tree[postn*2+1]);
        postn >>=1;
    }
}
void update(int pos, node new_val)
{
    pos+=(1<<n);
    tree[pos]=new_val;
    mergeup(pos);
}
```

Also what should I write inside the main function to make this thing work?
Suppose I have an array A={2,3,2,4,20394,21,-132,2832} , How I can use this code to find RMQ(1,4)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
1.What will the split function do here ?
```

Nothing: the function body is empty. There may be some other implementation where an action is required. (See Example 3) And see answer to 2b

```
2.... Where the value will be saved?
```

In the "val" field of the class/struct for which "merge" is called.

```
1b.What is the use of the array tree and what values will be kept there ?
```

Array "node tree[...]" stores all the nodes of the tree. Its element type is "struct node".

```
2b.What will this statement : tree[root].split(tree[left_child], tree[right_child]); do ?
```

It calls split for the struct node that's stored at index root, passing the nodes of the split node's children to it. What it actually does to tree[root] depends on the implementation of "split".

```
3b.What will those statements do ? :

node n;         // declare a new node
n.merge(l,r);   // call merge - store the minimum of l.val, r.val into n.val
return n;       // terminate the function and return n
```

I'll have to figure out the answers to your last Qs in the context of that code. Will take a little time.

**Later**
This should build a tree and do a range query. I'm not sure that the code on that page is correct. Anyway, the interface for range_query is not what you'd expect for easy usage.

```
int main(){
  int a[] = { -132, 1, 2, 3, 4, 21, 2832, 20394};
  for( int i = 0; i < 8; i++ ){
    node x;
    x.val = a[i];
    update( i, x);
  }

  node y = range_query(0, 8, 15, 8 + 1, 8 + 4 );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,it helped me a lot.I am just now stuck at taking input inside main function,updating A[i]=x and outputting the result.

Comment: @aroup This code should be in the context of a class with a proper constructor and hiding index offsetting. Then, clients can override the node's merge and split.